# How to connect to SQL Server which requires MFA without providing password in separate window

Tags: python, sql-server, active-directory, pyodbc, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to connect to SQL Server which requires multi factor authentication.
Each time when I am running script it want me to provide password.
Is there any way to avoid that and provide password automatically somehow?

When I tried to use password as connection parameter it shows me this error

```
Password option must not be specified, if Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
```

Code:

```
con = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"               
               "Server=tcp:sql-serrver.database.windows.net,1433;"
               "Database=db;"
               "UID=login@domain.com;"
               "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this I use ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication method instead of interactive

```
con = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"               
               "Server=tcp:sql-serrver.database.windows.net,1433;"
               "Database=db;"
               "UID=login@domain.com;"
               "PWD=pass123;"
               "Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword")
```